# Wire raspberry pi tft display, so as to keep the GPIO pins available for use

Tags: display

I got this product:  [http://www.amazon.com/PiTFT-Plus-480x320-Touchscreen-Raspberry/dp/B017PDWNKE?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017PDWNKE)

I would like to make it work with my Raspberry pi 2, however I don't want to just click it on because I am using pins 1, 7 (GPIO 4), 11 (GPIO 17), 17, and 40 (GPIO 21).  Here is the layout chart:  http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/circuitnotes/raspberry_pi_circuit_note_fig2a.jpg

I need a way to wire it from the raspberry pi with some sort of wired connector that would enable me to continue using those GPIO ports.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which GPIO are being used by the screen?  I doubt you can change the ones it needs so you'll have to change your own GPIO usage if there are any clashes.  There is no magic method of preventing clashes.

Comment: You need to dig up the schematics from the data sheets. Very few of the pins are actually in use (ie. most are NC/no-connect), so when you've got the schematic knowing which pins on the Pi are used, you can simply use jumpers for the necessary pins directly to the display, and use the rest of the pins as you see fit. The block connector is just a convenience thing...

Answer (score 1):

This display seems to use a few ports on the gpio as stated on the adafruit's website:

> The display uses the hardware SPI pins (SCK, MOSI, MISO, CE0, CE1) as well as GPIO #25 and #24. GPIO #18 can be used to PWM dim the backlight if you like. All other GPIO are unused.

There's also pins you can just use beside the gpio connector for you to use:

> There's a 2x16 'classic Pi' connection GPIO header on the bottom, you can connect a 26-pin Pi GPIO cable to it to use any of the other pins as you like. The other GPIO are broken out into solder pads at the bottom, in case you want to use more of the GPIO.

See: [Product page](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2441)

So... you still have many gpio pins to work with. Try plugin the screen to a breadboard, it'll be easier to tap onto those other pins! Here's [how to use a breadboard](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard).

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of the screen there should be some 2x16 gpio pins which you can use.

Comment: This type of reply is better suited as a comment. With that said, it's not very valuable as it doesn't provide any insight into the issue whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer to this, so I wend ahead and mapped all the pins myself. After sequentially removing pins until something failed I discovered that the pins used by are (I will be including the physical pin numbers in parenthesis for simplicity as per this diagram http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/howto/GPIO-Pinout-Rasp-Pi-1-Model-B-Rasp-Pi-2-Model-B):

- Any 5V (Pin 2 or 4)
- Any 3.3V (Pin 1 or 17)
- Any Ground (Pin 6, 9, 14, 20, 25, 30, 34, or 39)
- GPIO #18 (Pin 12) - Optional for backlight control
- GPIO #24 (Pin 18)
- GPIO10/SPI MOSI (Pin 19)
- GPIO #9/SPI MISO (Pin 21)
- GPIO #25 (Pin 22)
- GPIO #11/SPI CLK (Pin 23)
- GPIO #8/SPI CE0 (Pin 24)
- GPIO #7/SPI CE1 (Pin 26)

[image: GPIO Pin Diagram for Adafruit PiTFT - 320x240 2.8" TFT+Touchscreen for Raspberry Pi by cjonasw]