# Use GPIO Pins when attaching a HifiBerry MiniAmp

Tags: pi-zero, hifiberry, diy

I was building a little phoniebox (https://github.com/MiczFlor/RPi-Jukebox-RFID) for my son a couple of month ago and he loves it. So now I want to build an other one for a friend but would like to do it better now :)

So... I have a Raspberry Pi Zero and I also use a Hifi Berry MiniAmp (https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/miniamp/) Shield. The shield attaches to the Raspberry and just works fine.
The problem is that I need some additional GPIO Pins for an RDIF Reader as well as for some buttons.

On my first version I just soldered the cables on top of my MiniAmp, but as that's not what you are supposed to do it's a bit fiddly. The pins on top are very short so it's not cool to solder on there...

So I thought that there should be a better solution, right? Does anybody know some kind of PCB or so, that I can put on top of the GPIO pins that will extend them to the side but still let me attach my HifiBerry on top?

Is there anything like that available? Or how would you solve the issue?

Comment: Related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/66395/19949 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45927/19949 (soldering longer headerpins such that you can connect something on the bottom of the Pi's PCB)

Comment: Nice. Longer headerpins should work great! And I guess I can even solder a perfboard (is this english for the pcbs with the many holes in them, right?) between! I like the idea :)